# Laravel - How to prevent Laravel mails from going into junk mails

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use Laravel-5.8 for email notification with Sendgrid:

config/mail.php

```
return [

  'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

  'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),

  'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

  'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'usersupport@laravelapp.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'JFK'),
  ],

  'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

  'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','kkkddd'),

  'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','@kkkdhhhs'),

  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

  'markdown' => [
     'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
  ],

  'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

Here is the controller function.
Controller

```
public function publish_all_posts(){
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;    
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
    $userCode = Auth::user()->employee_code;
    $userFirstName = Auth::user()->first_name;
    $userLastName = Auth::user()->last_name;   


    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $reviewperiods = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $reviewperiod = $reviewperiods->appraisal_name;       

    $linemanager = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();
    $linemanageruserid = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('line_manager_id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();

    $linemanageruserids = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $linemanageruserid->line_manager_id)->first();      
    $linemanageremails = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('email')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();

    $linemanagerfirstnames = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('first_name')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();
    $linemanagerfirstname = $linemanagerfirstnames->first_name;
    $linemanagerlastnames = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('last_name')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();
    $linemanagerlastname = $linemanagerlastnames->last_name;
    $linemanagerids = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();
    $linemanagerid = $linemanagerids->id;

    $details = [
        'sent_to' => $linemanagerid,
        'sent_by' => $userId,
        'subject' => $userFirstName .' for '.$reviewperiod,
        'greeting' => 'Dear '.$linemanagerfirstname . ' '. $linemanagerlastname . ',',
        'body' =>  'Your direct report (' . $userFirstName . ' ' .$userLastName. ') ',
        'line1' => 'Your direct report (' . $userFirstName . ' ' .$userLastName. ') ',
        'line2' => 'has just completed the 3+1 goals for the year.',
        'line3' => 'Your reviews and approvals are required urgently.',
        'thanks' => 'Thank you!',            
        'user_fullname' => $userFirstName. ' ' . $userLastName,
        'user_code' => $userCode,
        'user_email' => $userEmail,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'line_manager_full_name' => $linemanagerfirstname. ' ' . $linemanagerlastname,
        'review_periond' => $reviewperiod,
        'line_manager_email' => $linemanageremail,
        'line_manager_id' => $linemanagerid,
        'notification_type' => 'goal setting',

    ];  

    Notification::route('mail', $details['line_manager_email'])
                ->notify(new \App\Notifications\Publish($details));

}
```

and this is the notification function.
Notificatiion

```
class Publish extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
 use Queueable;

 public function __construct($details)
 {
    $this->details = $details;
 }

 public function via($notifiable)
 {
    return ['mail'];
 }

 public function toMail($notifiable)
 {
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject($this->details['subject'])
                ->greeting($this->details['greeting'])
                ->line($this->details['line1'])
                ->line($this->details['line2'])
                ->line($this->details['line3'])
                ->line($this->details['thanks']);
 }        

 public function toArray($notifiable)
 {
    return [
        //
    ];
 }
}
```

Initially when users said they didn't receive any email, I thought that mails were not sent. Eventually I found out that the mails went to junk mail.

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show me Email sending function?

Comment: @lovecoding - I have updated the code. Thanks

Comment: I doubt this has to do with PHP, you should be looking in Sendgrid what happened to those emails. It could be that your sending address is not properly setup in Sendgrid, etc...